# Change font and effects

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is how my current HTML looks:

```
<div class="model-selection">
    <span id="model-selection-error-value"></span>
    <span id="model-selection-value"></span>
</div>
```

This is how my current CSS looks:

```
#model-selection-value
{
    color: blue;
}
```

The text is generated by a script (meaning text varies) but as of now the code creates a standard font with blue text.

```
<script>
var $errorDiv = $('#model-selection-error-value');
var $selectionDiv = $('#model-selection-value');
.........
```

This is what I want to achieve:

https://codepen.io/nw/pen/jhKtk

I thought I might would only copy/paste that CSS into mine, correct? What adjustmenst should I make to make this work?

***EDIT. This is what I currently have: (should be correct?)***

```
<div class="model-selection">
    <span id="model-selection-error-value"></span>
    <div class="logo"><span id="model-selection-value"></span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.model-selection
{
    position:         absolute;
    top:              0;
    left:             0;
    z-index:          5;
    margin:           0.3em;
    padding:          0.3em;
    font-size:        2em;
    font-family:      sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    border-radius:    8px;
}

#model-selection-error-value
{
    color: red;
}

#model-selection-value
{
    color: blue;
}

.logo {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo span {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(2.5em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(0.8);
  -moz-transform: perspective(2.5em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(0.8);
  -ms-transform: perspective(2.5em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(0.8);
  -o-transform: perspective(2.5em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(0.8);
  transform: perspective(2.5em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(0.8);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #fbd62a;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 0 1px 0 #7f6303, 0 3px 0 #846703, 0 5px 0 #896b03, 0 7px 0 #8e6f03, 0 9px 0 #937203, 0 6px 50px rgba(252, 223, 92, 0.8);
}
.logo span:first-line {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.logo span:hover {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(8em) rotateX(11deg) scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: perspective(8em) rotateX(11deg) scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: perspective(8em) rotateX(11deg) scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: perspective(8em) rotateX(11deg) scale(1.2);
  transform: perspective(8em) rotateX(11deg) scale(1.2);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 15px black, 0 1px 0 #7f6303, 0 2px 0 #846703, 0 0px 0 #896b03, 0 1px 0 #8e6f03, 0 2px 0 #937203, 0 2px 30px rgba(252, 223, 92, 0.6);
}
```

Comment: Please note that Java and Javascript are not the same language, in the same way that Austria and Australia are not the same country.

Comment: ok, thanks for editing!

Comment: This is not Css It's scss and it compiles to css. Either you need a scss Compiler (http://sass-lang.com/install) or you klick on the Arrow and then on "View compiled css". Afterwards you need to adapt the html-structure that is used in the codepen-Example (it has to be an `<a>` in a `<div class="logo">`).

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an idea of how I can make the <span id="model-selection-value"></span> into an div class? Edit: if it has to be within the <a> that means that the text has to be manually inputted? Like the current <a href="...">Naut<br>Drafter</a> ? or can I get my values from the script in there?

Comment: sure just use and copy the html in the codepen (This is the easy variant). If you need your `<span>`, you have to add the .logo-class to your container (`<div class="model-selection logo">`)and then rewrite the css (instead of `.logo a ` you need for example `.logo span`). Furthermore you cant have 2 spans, but only one so the code works properly.

Comment: What have you tried? If you show us what you have done so far, we might be able to help you with specific issues you are having. Please see [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: ,FluffyKitten I tried what @Matthias Gwiozda said, but I didn't get it to work :) I have edited what I currently have in my question.

Comment: Is this the result, you wanted to get https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvENJg ?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```js
var $error = $('#model-selection-error-value');
var $selection = $('#model-selection-value');

var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
 $selection.text(++i);
}, 150);
setInterval(function() {
 $error.text(i / 2);
}, 300);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #02111b;
}

.container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container span {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(2.5em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(0.8);
  -moz-transform: perspective(2.5em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(0.8);
  -ms-transform: perspective(2.5em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(0.8);
  -o-transform: perspective(2.5em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(0.8);
  transform: perspective(2.5em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(0.8);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #fbd62a;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 0 1px 0 #7f6303, 0 3px 0 #846703, 0 5px 0 #896b03, 0 7px 0 #8e6f03, 0 9px 0 #937203, 0 6px 50px rgba(252, 223, 92, 0.8);
}
.container span:first-line {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.container span:hover {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(8em) rotateX(11deg) scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: perspective(8em) rotateX(11deg) scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: perspective(8em) rotateX(11deg) scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: perspective(8em) rotateX(11deg) scale(1.2);
  transform: perspective(8em) rotateX(11deg) scale(1.2);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 15px black, 0 1px 0 #7f6303, 0 2px 0 #846703, 0 0px 0 #896b03, 0 1px 0 #8e6f03, 0 2px 0 #937203, 0 2px 30px rgba(252, 223, 92, 0.6);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="model-selection container">
    <span id="model-selection-error-value"></span><br />
    <span id="model-selection-value"></span>
</div>
```